# Study the differentiability of these functions

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, cauchy-riemann-equations

I have the following functions: $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ and $g:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, defined as

$$f(z)=z^2e^{\bar{z}}, \quad g(z)=\sin(z)f(z)$$

I am trying to solve this using Cauchy-Riemann equations, but I am struggling with the definition of $u$ and $v$

$$
u(x,y)= \text{Re}[f(x+iy)] \;\;\;\; v(x,)= \text{Im} [f(x+iy)]
$$

Any hints? Should I try a different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the best approach.

It should be clear that $f$ is differentiable at $0$. If $z\ne0$; then $f$ is differentiable at $z$ if and only if $\varphi(z)=e^{\overline z}$ is differentiabl at $z$. And it is much easier to apply the Cauchy-Riemann equations method to $\varphi$. If $x,y\in\Bbb R$, then$$\varphi(x+yi)=e^x(\cos(y)-\sin(y)i)$$and therefore you should take $u(x,y)=e^x\cos(y)$ and $v(x,y)=-e^x\sin(y)$.

Comment: And after that, as $z^2$ is obviosly differentiable, $f$ will be differentiable where $\varphi$ is, right? And the same argument for $g$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In the case of $g$, you should deal first with the function $\psi(z)=\sin(z)e^{\overline z}$.